# How to add a static content to Bootstrap carousel?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

Here I have code for Bootstarp carousel and it is working fine for all the different devices.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="img/t1/p-banner1.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Image 1</h3>
          <p>Image 1 Description</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="img/sizeimg/dal.png" alt=""/>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Image 1</h3>
          <p>Image 1 Description</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="img/sizeimg/url.jpg" alt=""/>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Image 1</h3>
          <p>Image 1 Description</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>

  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>

</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.carousel').carousel();
  });
</script>
```

Now, my doubt is that, How can I add some content like buttons(Login, Register) which is common on all slides to the carousel? And it is always be the centre to the slide image and it should be responsive as well.

Code of the buttons is shown below. And this what appears on all the slides as static.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="btn-group" aria-label="...">
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" style="background:black;opacity: 0.5; color:white;">LOGIN</a>
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" style="background:black;opacity: 0.5; color:white;">REGISTER</a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I have tried in different ways, and it working fine for large devices but not for the small devices and due to these buttons, in mobile devices right nav button of the carousel is not working.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: place them in a div with fixed position?

Comment: Even though I placed them in a div with fixed position there is no change at all!

Comment: Did you try adding it to the carousel caption div?

Comment: If I give css to carousel caption, I have to place static content on every slide. am I right? @ArshadMuhammed

Comment: Yes. You don't want to do that?

Comment: If you have a navbar you can add these buttons to that. : justasuggestion

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your style
 position :Static; top: %; right: %;
 for button class

Reference for positioning:http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp